# Can you call a pass from an LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I am writing my own LLVM pass, which modifies the LLVM bitcode. While generating the bitcode, I want to disable inlining of functions, but when I am done with modifiying the bitcode, I want to call the pass which performs inlining of functions. Can this be done. If yes, how?

To better understand, what I am saying, look at the following code.

```
bool MyBitCodeModifier::runOnModule(Module &M)
{
   // Here is the code of my pass which modifies bitcode
   // I need to call inline pass here
}
```

Comment: can you not call inline-pass from the place where your function `MyBitCodeModifier::runOnModule` returns.

Answer (score 1):

For inlining you don't need to call the pass. Use `InlineFunction` instead. You can find definition in `include/llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h`.

But if you insist on calling of inlining pass after yours, you can modify `PassManager` to run passes in order you want.